# Change color of the edited text from the datagridview richtextbox cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, colors, richtextbox

From this [How can i manage changed value text by highlighting the edited text only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629892/how-can-i-manage-changed-value-text-by-highlighting-the-edited-text-only) question that i have asked yesterday, am trying all by best to make it work and it is not working.

Can anyone please help me. this morning i tried this logic to see if i can apply it to the grid but it is not

```
 public void Mixedcolors()
    {
        RichTextBoxPrintNameColors.Font = new Font("Consolas", 18f, FontStyle.Bold);
        RichTextBoxPrintNameColors.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        string[] _Colornames = { "Lion", "Monkey", "Kudu" };
        Color[] colors = { Color.Red, Color.Red, Color.Yellow, };
            for (int i = 0; i < _Colornames.Length; i++)
            {
                string _names = _Colornames[i];
                Color color = colors[i];
                {
                    RichTextBoxPrintNameColors.SelectionBackColor = color;
                    RichTextBoxPrintNameColors.AppendText(_names);
                    RichTextBoxPrintNameColors.SelectionBackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
                    RichTextBoxPrintNameColors.AppendText(" ");
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: As I have said before the real challenge is not the coloring but the list of changes! If you have a list of strings and the colors they are supposed to have, the painting is not so hard; but creating/maintaining that list is __a lot harder__ than it seems to be at fist glance!! See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348766/change-color-of-edited-text-to-red/29351999#29351999) for both an example and a discussion of the real problems (aka 'diff') !

Comment: Let me have a look and see if i will get help as the other thing is lack of knowledge

Comment: where must i put this codding for testing

SolidBrush c1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
SolidBrush c2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

diffStrings.Add(new Tuple<SolidBrush, string>(c1, "1234"));
diffStrings.Add(new Tuple<SolidBrush, string>(c2, "M"));
diffStrings.Add(new Tuple<SolidBrush, string>(c1, "1234"));
diffStrings.Add(new Tuple<SolidBrush, string>(c2, "ÖÄÜ"));
diffStrings.Add(new Tuple<SolidBrush, string>(c1, "1234"));
diffStrings.Add(new Tuple<SolidBrush, string>(c2, "ÖÄÜ"));
diffStrings.Add(new Tuple<SolidBrush, string>(c1, "1234"));

Comment: These lines intialize two brushes and an example list. put the brushes at class level with the list declaration and put the add calls maybe in the formload or some other inti section..